# How to enable web page alerts in our simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, xcode4.3

Is their any property for enable java script alerts in our webview?

In android code is-

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I search in google but i didn't find any help for use this type of property in our objective-c.

Is there any similar property in iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java script is by default enabled and can not be disabled.So you won't need to bother about that.

Comment: But i open webpage programmatically.The alerts are not shown in  simulator.